# Can't compile bitvec 0.19.4 "multiple `BITS` found"

Tags: rust, build, compiler-errors, rust-cargo

I ran `cargo update` on my application and can now no longer compile the app. I am not really sure where to start debugging this issue since the errors are in a library that I am not familiar with.

[image]

Cargo.toml

```toml
[package]
name = "web-app"
version = "1.1.0"
authors = ["Me <my_emailg@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix = "0.10"
actix-web = { version = "3.3.2", default-features = false }
actix-rt = "1.1.1"
async-trait = "0.1.42"
lapin = { version = "1.6.6", features = ["rustls"], default-features = false }
futures = "0.3.12"
handlebars = "3.5.2"
jsonwebtoken = "7.2.0"
listenfd = "0.3.3"
log = "0.4.14"
paperclip = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["actix"] }
rand = "0.8.2"
ring = "0.16.19"
rust-argon2 = "0.8.3"
rustls = "0.19.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.121", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.61"
slog-scope = "4.4.0"
slog-stdlog = "4.1.0"
validator = "0.12.0"
zxcvbn = "2.1.1"
bitvec = "0.21.0"

[dev-dependencies]
fake = "2.4.0"
```

rustc version: 1.50.0; Ubuntu: 20.10

In the interest of brevity I have not posted the 43 errors that occurred, nor the entirety of my code base.

Answer (score 1):

Issues have been created on the [bitvec](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/issues/105) and [funty](https://github.com/myrrlyn/funty/issues/3) repositories regarding this error.

> As a temporary workaround you can force it to use version `1.1.0` of `funty` in your `Cargo.toml`
>
> ```toml
> [dependencies]
> funty = "=1.1.0"
> ```